# Interpretting and Using fdrtool?

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

With the help of articles like [this one](http://www.nonlinear.com/support/progenesis/comet/faq/v2.0/pq-values.aspx), I am beginning to understand false discovery rate first laid out by Benjamini and Hochberg ([1995](http://articles.viriya.net/controlling_the_false_discovery_rate_a_practical_and_powerful_approach_to_multiple_testing.pdf)). I am also seeing the value of the "unified" approach proffered by Strimmer ([2008](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-9-303)) and that is operationalized in the [`fdrtool`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fdrtool/fdrtool.pdf) package for `R`.

However, I'm still as loss how to interpret and use the output of `fdrtool` despite Strimmer's [guide](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/24/12/1461/196272).

Given the following code:

```
    set.seed(42)
    fake.ps <- abs(rnorm(50, mean = .01, sd = .5)) # N = 50 is too few, but don't want to make output too long
    fake.ps <- as.vector(fake.ps)
    fdrtool(fake.ps, statistic = "pvalue", plot = TRUE, verbose = TRUE, cutoff.method = "fndr", color.figure = TRUE)
```

I'm at an embarrassingly-continued loss to interpret the output:

```
    There may be too few input test statistics for reliable FDR calculations!Step 1... determine cutoff point
    Step 2... estimate parameters of null distribution and eta0
    Censored sample for null model estimation has only size 1 !Step 3... compute p-values and estimate empirical PDF/CDF
    Step 4... compute q-values and local fdr
    Step 5... prepare for plotting
    
    $pval
     [1] 0.001860305 0.008447593 0.008728875 0.020155198 0.025105174 0.026979612 0.035764286 0.035955628 0.040291179
    [10] 0.042641376 0.044729140 0.045851875 0.050991716 0.059017596 0.060522341 0.062547683 0.068930868 0.083569065
    [19] 0.083761347 0.090754981 0.096698466 0.100930060 0.106638773 0.106821794 0.120839324 0.127297507 0.128002710
    [28] 0.138601740 0.150056436 0.150149764 0.157261319 0.177323814 0.181834089 0.182955596 0.188538502 0.189113116
    [37] 0.204356477 0.227154971 0.237650466 0.243433910 0.248800493 0.257247331 0.267535049 0.279801426 0.296484386
    [46] 0.300308964 0.308917632 0.339011172 0.347891784 0.373045689
    
    $qval
     [1] 0.002967210 0.004617400 0.004640888 0.005571380 0.005744874 0.005795932 0.005970499 0.005973439 0.006033201
    [10] 0.006060918 0.006083280 0.006094526 0.006146921 0.006211707 0.006222066 0.006235271 0.006409554 0.006732547
    [19] 0.006736217 0.006861468 0.006956688 0.007019047 0.007096870 0.007099254 0.007400538 0.007523988 0.007536948
    [28] 0.007720525 0.007897868 0.007899232 0.007999735 0.008250489 0.008301079 0.008313365 0.008372857 0.008378828
    [37] 0.008715367 0.009174191 0.009369454 0.009473128 0.009566956 0.009710204 0.009877726 0.010068135 0.010312092
    [46] 0.010365741 0.010483564 0.011145955 0.011333602 0.012143113
    
    $lfdr
     [1] 0.005477728 0.005477728 0.006579072 0.006579072 0.006579072 0.006579072 0.006579072 0.006579072 0.006579072
    [10] 0.006579072 0.006579072 0.006657506 0.006657506 0.006657506 0.006657506 0.008827220 0.008827220 0.008827220
    [19] 0.008827220 0.008827220 0.008827220 0.008827220 0.008827220 0.010937974 0.010937974 0.010937974 0.010937974
    [28] 0.010937974 0.010937974 0.010937974 0.010937974 0.010937974 0.010937974 0.010937974 0.010937974 0.017371792
    [37] 0.017371792 0.017371792 0.017371792 0.017371792 0.017371792 0.017371792 0.017371792 0.017371792 0.017371792
    [46] 0.017371792 0.031718415 0.031718415 1.000000000 1.000000000
    
    $statistic
    [1] "pvalue"
    
    $param
            cutoff N.cens       eta0    eta0.SE
    [1,] 0.3730457      1 0.03190025 0.03157964
```

[image]

More specifically:

1. Based on the output, how do I determine where to set the cut-off for significance under FDR where a one-tailed α = .05;
2. What are the meaning and use of the `$lfdr`s in relation to the *q*-values? (Or to whatever);
3. What are the meanings and uses of the parameters under `$parm`, i.e., `cutoff`, `N.cens`, `eta0` (`eta0.SE` I understand as the standard error of the η<sub>0</sub> term).

Comment: Have a look at [B Efron's paper](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~ckirby/brad/papers/2005LocalFDR.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problems in the example

Please consider the following issues to understand the particular output of fdrtool:

In the example there are too little data points that constitute the background. fdrtool assumes that the data consists of two types of points. One type that follow the null hypothesis (background or "Null-Component" in the plot) and anothers that dose not follow the null hypothesis ("Alternative Component" in the plot). Since points that follow the null hypothesis have a uniform distribution of p-values, fdrtool is capable of explaining the observed distribution of p-values as a combination of this uniform distribution and an alternative component. p-values are never normally distributed, so using normally distributed values here breaks some assumptions.

### Answers

1. Lower fdr values are better. So if you want to select all points with an an fdr below 0.05 do so with the index from `result$lfdr < 0.05`. Alternatively, if you want to select a set of points in which only 5% of points may be false positives, do so with the index from `result$qval < 0.05`.
2. `lfdr` represents the local false discovery rate for a specific point and `qval` represents the average false discovery rate in the set of points with the same or lower `qval`.
3. `cutoff` is a value of the input statistic (in this case p-values) below which data points are excluded to estimate the ratio of Null-Component" and "Alternative Component". `N.cens` shows the number of data points that have been excluded based on `cutoff`. `eta0` is the fraction of the data points that may be explained by the null-hypothesis. E.g., if `eta0` is 1, then all your data seems to follow the null hypothesis.